# populate jlist at gui class from entity class

Tags: java, swing, entity-framework, jdbc, jlist

I know this is a common question for there are videos all around, but they brought me closer to but not the goal.

According to recommended practices, I have packaged files into:
- boundary (GUI classes)
- entity (getters, setters, populateJList())
- database (db access object)

I wish to populate my JList that is located @ boundary, via the following method @ Entity. How can I do so, explicitly?

```
    public void populateJList()
    {
        DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();

    ResultSet rs = null;
    DataAccessObject db = new DataAccessObject();
    db.setUp("customer");

    String dbQuery = "SELECT food_Category FROM store_owner";       
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);

    try
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            food_Category = rs.getString("food_Category");

            m.addElement(food_Category);
        }       
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.terminate();
    //return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to populate my JList that is located @ boundary, via the following method

Then you need to change your method signature to return the ListModel. Something like:

```
public ListModel populateJList()
{
    DefaultListMoodel model = new DefaultListModel();

    ...

    return model;
}
```

Now when you invoke the method your code would be something like:

```
JList list = new JList( populateModel() );
```

Comment: thank you. so if my class @ entity is named 'Food', i'll do the following: 
  Food food = new Food();
  JList list = new JList(food.populateJList());

Comment: also, i tried to do a println @ populateModel() but it doesnt work out. so i went ahead to try your suggestion & all the jlist displayed was a []. does that mean my DAO is incorrect?

Comment: I've never used DAO, so I don't know how it works. Normally if a query doesn't return any rows the DefaultListModel would just be empty since nothing was added to it. If you see "[]" then it seems like the query is returning that value. All you need to do is at a println(...) statement to while loop to see what data is being returned.